# Выделяется красным addTextChangedListener (kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Проблема с *addTextChangedListener*, выдает ошибку **Unresolved reference: addTextChangedListener**. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как убрать эту ошибку, ведь у других она не проявляется.
*Вот код:*

```
register_input_code.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            val string = register_input_code.toString()
            if(string.length==6){
                verifCode()
            }
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        }
    })
}

fun verifCode() {
    Toast.makeText(activity, "Ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Comment: Так а что есть `register_input_code`? Покажите объявление/инициализацию.

Comment: Объявляется переменной var register_input_code = R.id.register_input_code, register_input_code это InputText

Comment: findViewById(id) сделан. Как можно задать register_input_code, какой это тип?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R.id.register_input_code` - это число-идентификатор, с помощью которого можно найти элемент разметки методом `findViewById()`, получить ссылку на элемент можно так:

```kotlin
val register_input_code = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.register_input_code)
register_input_code.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {...})
```

**P.S.** Вот вам шаблон инициализации вью во фрагментах:

```kotlin
class EnterCodeFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_enter_code) {

    private lateinit var register_input_code: EditText

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        register_input_code = view.findViewById(R.id.register_input_code)
        register_input_code.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {...})
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: var register_input_code = R.id.register_input_code, у меня она обьявлена, хочу уточнить, у меня тип файла Fragment ( class EnterCodeFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_enter_code) { ), find по ид там не работает

Comment: Вы видите как она объявлена у меня - разница есть? У вас ей присвоен идентификатор (число типа `Int`), а не ссылка на `EditText`.

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло мне. Благодорю.

Comment: Ну зачем же учить называть переменные `register_input_code`? :)